# Getting the properties of a parameter object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

Hi I am just learning reflection and I am attempting to read the the parameters on the actions in controllers that are decorated with the attribute T4ValidateAttribute.

Lets take an example:

```
 public class LoginModelDTO
{      
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Username should not have more then 50 chars")]
    [MinLength(25 , ErrorMessage = "Username should have at least 25 chars")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

[T4ValidateAttribute]
public bool LogIn(LoginModelDTO modelDTO)
{
    return m_loginService.Login(modelDTO);
}
```

My controllers are in a project called prokect.WebApi and my DTO's are in a project called project.DomainServices.Contracts.
I will not be adding the ControllerInfo because it works if you guys think it's needed I will add it.

```
 //This code get all the controllers that inherit from the BaseApiController     
 List<Type> controllers = ControllersInfo.GetControllers<BaseApiController>("project.WebApi");

 foreach (var controller in controllers)
 {
    //This retrives a Dictionary that has the key the method name and the valie an array of ParameterInfo[]
     var actions = ControllersInfo.GetAllCustomActionsInController(controller, new T4ValidateAttribute());
     foreach (var parameterInfose in actions)
     {
         var parameters = parameterInfose.Value;
         foreach (var parameterInfo in parameters)
         {
            //This is where I do not knwo what to do   
         }
       }
    }
```

If you ooked at the code a bit and read the comments you can see that at this point I can access from each action it's parameters.

In our example the return parameter will be of type LoginModelDTO.

From here on I would like to itarate over all of the properties of this object for each property to get it's CustomAttributes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your example code, the parameters ***do not have attributes*** - the methods and properties do; is this intentional?

Comment: Method parameters or object properties? I'm not quite sure what you're after..

Comment: terminology wise, these seems to be some confusion in the question - you are getting the "custom actions", which are *methods*, but you are calling the variables `parameters`, `parameterInfo`, etc - are you conflating methods and parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the simplest level:

```
var attribs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(parameterInfo);
```

If all the attributes you are interested in have a common base type, you can restrict it to:

```
var attribs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(parameterInfo,
                    typeof(CommonBaseAttribute));
```

Then you just loop over `attribs` and pick what you care about. If you think there is at most one of a particular type:

```
SomeAttributeType attrib = (SomeAttributeType)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
       parameterInfo, typeof(SomeAttributeType));
if(attrib != null) {
     // ...
}
```

And finally, if you **just** want to know if the attribute is declared, this is much cheaper than `GetCustomAttribute[s]`:

```
if(Attribute.IsDefined(parameterInfo, typeof(SomeAttributeType))) {
     // ...
}
```

Note, however, that in your example the parameters **do not have attributes**.

Comment: There are also overloads of those methods that take generic parameters instead of a Type parameter (.NET 4.5+).  For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194330.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638541/how-to-get-all-action-names-from-a-controller).

Basically they're using `ReflectedControllerDescriptor` to get list of `ActionDescriptor` instances (I think you are doing something similar in `ControllersInfo.GetAllCustomActionsInController` method):

```
var actionDescriptors = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(GetType())
  .GetCanonicalActions();
foreach(var action in actionDescriptors)
{
   object[] attributes = action.GetCustomAttributes(false);

   // if you want to get your custom attribute only
   var t4Attributes = action.GetCustomAttributes(false)
    .Where(a => a is T4ValidateAttribute).ToList();

}
```