# Mvc Areas-Controller-Action Listing for URL Authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, model-view-controller

## it can be a different method.  As a result, i want to get all the urls from the application.

I planning authorization in the my application. And, I need these (area name, controller name, action name) to ask when a request is made. In short, the URL address. I tried these.

> **Example:**
>
> - Trial *(AreaRegistration)*
>
>   - Trial1Controller
>
>     - Home ActionResult    **>>>** /Trial/Trial1/Home/
>     - A ActionResult           **>>>** /Trial/Trial1/A/
>     - B ActionResult           **>>>** /Trial/Trial1/B/
>   - Trial2Controller
> - Examp *(AreaRegistration)*
>
>   - Examp1Controller
>
>     - Home ActionResult    **>>>** /Examp/Examp1/Home/
>     - A ActionResult;          **>>>** /Examp/Examp1/A/
>   - Examp2Controller
>
>     - Home ActionResult    **>>>** /Examp/Examp2/Home/

```
var areas = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(AreaRegistration).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
foreach(var area in areas)
{
    var controllers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToList();
    foreach (var controller in controllers)
    {
         var methods = controller.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
         foreach (var method in methods)
         {
              if (method.ReturnType == typeof(ActionResult))
              {
                    lstControllerActions.Add(string.Format("Area -> Controller -> Action : {0} -> {1} -> {2}", area.Name, controller.Name, method.Name));
              }
         }
     }
}
```

> **lstControllerActions** Result:
>
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Trial1 -> Home
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Trial1 -> A
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Trial1 -> B
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Examp1 -> Home
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Examp1 -> A
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Examp2 -> Home
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Examp-> Trial1 -> Home
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Trial1 -> A
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Trial1 -> B
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Examp1 -> Home
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Examp1 -> A
> - Area -> Controller -> Action : Trial -> Examp2 -> Home

Everything is beautiful but, No connection controller between area.

#### HELP

Comment: Please answer the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is solved. quotation from **@kamal-hamidi**, thanks.

[quote is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35225796/get-all-area-controller-and-action-as-a-tree)

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = GetSubClasses<Controller>();

    // Get all controllers with their actions
    var getAllcontrollers = (from item in list
        let name = item.Name
        where !item.Name.StartsWith("T4MVC_") // I'm using T4MVC
        select new MyController()
        {
            Name = name.Replace("Controller", ""), Namespace = item.Namespace, MyActions = GetListOfAction(item)
        }).ToList();

    // Now we will get all areas that has been registered in route collection
    var getAllAreas = RouteTable.Routes.OfType<Route>()
        .Where(d => d.DataTokens != null && d.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area"))
        .Select(
            r =>
                new MyArea
                {
                    Name = r.DataTokens["area"].ToString(),
                    Namespace = r.DataTokens["Namespaces"] as IList<string>,
                }).ToList().GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();

    // Add a new area for default controllers
    getAllAreas.Insert(0, new MyArea()
    {
        Name = "Main",
        Namespace = new List<string>()
        {
            typeof (Web.Controllers.HomeController).Namespace
        }
    });


    foreach (var area in getAllAreas)
    {
        var temp = new List<MyController>();
        foreach (var item in area.Namespace)
        {
            temp.AddRange(getAllcontrollers.Where(x => x.Namespace == item).ToList());
        }
        area.MyControllers = temp;
    }

    return View(getAllAreas);
}

private static List<Type> GetSubClasses<T>()
{
    return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
        type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))).ToList();
}

private IEnumerable<MyAction> GetListOfAction(Type controller)
{
    var navItems = new List<MyAction>();

    // Get a descriptor of this controller
    ReflectedControllerDescriptor controllerDesc = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller);

    // Look at each action in the controller
    foreach (ActionDescriptor action in controllerDesc.GetCanonicalActions())
    {
        bool validAction = true;
        bool isHttpPost = false;

        // Get any attributes (filters) on the action
        object[] attributes = action.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        // Look at each attribute
        foreach (object filter in attributes)
        {
            // Can we navigate to the action?
            if (filter is ChildActionOnlyAttribute)
            {
                validAction = false;
                break;
            }
            if (filter is HttpPostAttribute)
            {
                isHttpPost = true;
            }

        }

        // Add the action to the list if it's "valid"
        if (validAction)
            navItems.Add(new MyAction()
            {
                Name = action.ActionName,
                IsHttpPost = isHttpPost
            });
    }
    return navItems;
}

public class MyAction
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsHttpPost { get; set; }
}

public class MyController
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MyAction> MyActions { get; set; }
}

public class MyArea
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Namespace { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MyController> MyControllers { get; set; }
}
```